# Choice of the word indicating a job title

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am translating text in a blank form which will be sent by my organization to another organization. In this blank form I have to write a general word indicating a job position of an employee, i.e. a person who will fill out this form on behalf of his or her organization. I wrote the words 'Full Name' of a receiver or an employee. And I also need a word signifying a job title of a receiver.

Which word is the most suitable for such a form? I am hesitating between **'job title'**, **'job position'**,  **'position'** and **'post'**. Which word is the clearest and does not give rise to questions?

Comment: I'm not sure on what a formal form will have, but "profession:..." and "career:..." seem like the best choices for me. "Post", not a chance.

Comment: I am not speaking about a job application. This is another context which is not related to the HR department. This is a request directed to an employee of another company. This request is like a blank form.

Comment: If you want to know someone's job title, you use *job title*. That does not 'give rise to questions'.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Though it's really hard to get sth out of what you've written there. You lost me. :D

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear. I deleted the word 'applicant' because the context has nothing to do with a job application or human resources. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somewhat depends on what precisely you mean. Of your options listed, "job title" seems the most sensible and most likely to be encountered.

"Job position" is not a combination I have heard of, but you can easily guess its meaning.

"Position" is sometimes used, but I would expect it more likely to be used in conversation than on a form

Example:

> "What is your position at this company"

"Post" has an older, more British or military sound to it, so probably not a good fit.

If you are asking what the person does now at their current employer, job title is good. If you want to know what they do in general for employment then profession or career might be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide between "potential addressee" or "applicant" for this question.  Addressee lacks context. *Occupation* is the typical word on forms sent out to "addressees", whereas with an applicant, one might want to know their previous Job Title.

Job titles vary from organization to organization, whereas "occupation" is a much narrower, and much more regular, list.

OCCUPATIONS
Farmer
Clerk
Accountant
Doctor
Attorney
Sales Rep

etc

A *Job Title* might be "Assistant Vice-President", or "Chief of Staff", or "Human Resources Manager", or "Director of Operations for The Americas|Pacific Rim|Emerging Markets".

Comment: Since the OP mentions (in edit) that the field relates to the person filling out the form on behalf of their organization, job title would be appropriate.

Comment: @eques Yes, 'job title' is what I am looking for. But why are you writing a job title without an article in some places? I am just curious about it. :)

Comment: @Humbulani What do you mean about the article? I say "job title" since you mentioned it was a label on a form. You wouldn't likely hear "a job title" or "the job title" in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

- "**Role applied for**", or "**Position applied for**" - for the new
  *job position*;
- "**Applicant's full name**" - for their name, and;
- "**Current Occupation**" - for their current job.

That's what we used all the last few corporations that I worked for. They tend to lend the form an air of formally, which you don't really get when using the word *job*. Although, ironically, I think that we used "Job description" for the larger description in the advertisement...

Hope that helps.